# Can't Install postgresql-9.3 on ubunutu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql-9.3

When i tried to install postgresql-9.3 or higher it shows me the below errors

$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3

- Reading package lists... Done
- Building dependency tree
- Reading state information... Done
- Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
  requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
  distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
  or been moved out of Incoming.
- The following information may help to resolve the situation:
- The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  postgresql-9.3 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.16) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.12 is to be installed
- E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Try this `sudo apt-get install libc6=2.13-20ubuntu5`  or `sudo apt-get install libc6=2.15-0ubuntu10.12`

Comment: I tried both the command but no luck..
after 1 command run 
- Reading package lists... Done
- Building dependency tree       
- Reading state information... Done
- E: Version '2.13-20ubuntu5' for 'libc6' was not found

After 2nd command run 
- Reading package lists... Done
- Building dependency tree       
- Reading state information... Done
- E: Version '2.15-0ubuntu10.1' for 'libc6' was not found

Answer (score 6):

I had very similar problem, turns out I had added 14.04 repo instead of 12.04

After doing as [suggested](https://gist.github.com/pyk/8243010)

```
echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3
```

it worked fine

Comment: I fixed a very similar problem here. I was trying to install on Precise (12.04) using Trusty (14.04) repos. After changing to the correct repo the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the apt-get update before installing postgresql:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```